# How to send dynamic SOAP XML req payload in RestAssured

Tags: java, soap, rest-assured

I'd like to send dynamic parameter into SOAP XML which I later use as a body in my RestAssured test. How to do it? I've tried to pass it as a formParam but it says that "You can either send form parameters OR body content in POST, not both!".

```
   Response response = given()
                .header("Content-Type", "text/xml")
                .and()
                .formParam("paramName", "paramValue")
                .body(IOUtils.toString(fileInputStream,"UTF-8"))
                .when()
                .post()
                .then()
                .statusCode(200)
```

And part of my XML looks like this:

```
<dms:paramName>${paramValue}</dms:paramName>
```

Answer (score 1):

I've found this solution:

```
    private static String generateStringFromResource(String path) throws IOException {
        return new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(path)));
    }
```

```
        String req= generateStringFromResource ("pathToXML")
                .replace("parameter", paramValue);
```